# Comparing the Samuel and Stone-Čech compactifications of a Hausdorff topological group

Tags: general-topology, compactness, topological-groups, uniform-spaces

Let $G$ be an Hausdorff topological group and let $\beta G$ be the Stone-Čech compactification of $G$.

Now, $G$ is also a uniform space with respect to the so-called right uniformity. Let $S(G)$ be the  Samuel compactification of $G$.

- Given a uniform space $( X , \mathcal{U} )$ there is a finest uniformity $\mathcal{U}_0$ on $X$ which is totally bounded and coarser than $\mathcal{U}$. The Samuel compactification of $( X , \mathcal{U} )$ is then the completion of $( X , \mathcal{U}_0 )$.

Are $\beta G$ and $S(G)$ the same space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the following.

A typical answer is negative, since the right-uniformity may be not fine and so there may exists a bounded continuous but not uniformly continuous function $f$ (for instance, put $G=\Bbb R$ endowed with the standard topology and $f(x)=\sin x^2$). Then $f$ extends to $\beta G$ but it does not extends to $S(G)$, because $f$ is not uniformly continuous with respect to $\mathcal U_0$ (because $\mathcal U_0\subset\mathcal U$).

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but it seems correct. Thank you.

Comment: @PrimoPetri The answer may be positive for some small classes of groups, for  instance, for pseudocompact groups.